# Change tab colour based on cell value, runtime error

Tags: excel, vba

On each tab of my workbook, cell I1 calculates Print if the tab should be printed (meets criteria)

I am trying to code each tab to look at I1 and change tab colour if `I1 = "Print"`. All of the codes that I am trying end up resulting in a `Runtime error 1004`.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

EDIT 1: The error is thrown up at

### .Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)

### EDIT 2: I have switched to Calculate from Change. Thanks for that.

EDIT 3: I have two module codes in the same book which password protect/unprotect all tabs. Could this be interfering?

```
Sub protect_all_sheets()  
top:  
pass = InputBox("password?")  
repass = InputBox("Verify Password")  
If Not (pass = repass) Then  
MsgBox "you made a boo boo"  
GoTo top  
End If  
 For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count  
 If Worksheets(i).ProtectContents = True Then GoTo oops  
 Next  
 For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets  
 s.Protect Password:=pass  
 Next  
 Exit Sub  
 oops: MsgBox "I think you have some sheets that are already protected. Please unprotect all sheets then running this Macro."  
End Sub  


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MyVal = Range("I1").Text

    With ActiveSheet.Tab
        Select Case MyVal
            Case "Print"
                .Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)
            Case Else
                .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Use `Range("I1").Value` rather than `.Text`. It would also be a good idea to use `Option Explicit` on the top of your modules.

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered by calculations: you need `Worksheet_Calculate`

Comment: Your problem description is in terms of `I7` but your code mentions `I1`.

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered by calculations: you need `Worksheet_Calculate`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.tab.color = IIf(Me.Range("I1").value="Print",vbRed,vbWhite)
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't say it did ?   But that's not really relevant if the main issue is that the Change event won't work in this instance.

Comment: You probably are right that OP should use `Calculate` rather than `Change`, but their description of the error seems to suggest that there is something else happening with their code, something which switching to `Calculate` is unlikely to fix. OP's posted code shouldn't trigger a runtime error, so I don't see how there is really enough info to answer it. Still, this should help them if they fix whatever it is that is crashing, so +1

Comment: I have corrected my problem description with the correct cell value, thank you John!

Comment: So I have amended the code as follows:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    MyVal = Range("I1").Value
    
    With ActiveSheet.Tab
        Select Case MyVal
            Case "Print"
                .Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)
            Case Else
                .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone  <- the error is thrown here
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Is your sheet protected?